# Finding Max date from a row that has 28 date columns based on conditions

Tags: date, max

I have a situation in my code and the data looks like this
for each participant for that particular plan he belongs to we get only one single row.
in that row we have 28 date fields.
I am trying to pull up his match eligibility date for year end 20222, so i need the latest date in year 2022

so this is the logic

It can have dates for year 2023, 2022, 2021,...
and the dates in this columns are stored in desending order with latest date first and so on.
so at any point of time Date_Field_1 : will have the earliest date
Table will not have data for future yeas like 2024

condition 1: If Date_Field_1 = "any date with year 2022" , just take this date
don't need to check any other dates, as I need the latest date for year 2022
we can exit

condition 2: If the year value in the Date_Field_1 < 2022
we just take this value

Condition 3 : If the year value in Date_Field_1 > 2022 (i.e if year = 2023)
the sequentially check all date fields until we find a date with year 2022
If we find a date with year 2022, we take it.
If no 2022 dates are found, then we pick the earliest date whichever is available.

please suggest on how we can achieve this in sql

I tried if else case but it becomes very long and have to add so many  conditions